# Combining with row above under certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Table format (empty cells are null, columns are: field, dimension)

```
field | dimension
-----------------
a     | 
b     | abc
e     | efg
      | xyz
r     | abc
      | def
      | xyz
```

Desired format:

```
field | dimension
-----------------
a     | [nan]
b     | [abc]
e     | [efg, xyz]
r     | [abc, def, xyz]
```

I tried:

```
df.dimension = [df.dimension]
```

And was going to find the index of each empty cell in field and combine with the row above. However, I got -

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.

I also figured there has to be a better way than the way I was approaching it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes - I will clarify in the post.

Comment: Please change your desired output by accepted answer, because first value is `NaN`, not `[NaN]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df['field'] = df['field'].ffill()
df_out = df.groupby('field')['dimension'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  field        dimension
0     a            [nan]
1     b            [abc]
2     e       [efg, xyz]
3     r  [abc, def, xyz]
```

Comment: ++ for changing back the picture ! :)

Comment: @Wen  LOL.  Thanks.

Comment: @user8766186 I am glad that helped.  You are welcome.

Comment: @ScottBoston - please change your solution with `ffill` only for first column - second column contains NaNs, so output should be wrong if `ffill` is applied to all data.

Comment: @jezrael Great idea.  Done.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df =(df.groupby(df['field'].ffill())['dimension']
       .apply(lambda x: np.nan if x.isnull().all() else list(x))
       .reset_index())
print (df)
  field        dimension
0     a              NaN
1     b            [abc]
2     e       [efg, xyz]
3     r  [abc, def, xyz]
```

---

```
df = (df[df['dimension'].notnull()].groupby(df['field'].ffill())['dimension']
                                  .apply(list)
                                  .reindex(pd.unique(df['field'].dropna()))
                                  .reset_index())
print (df)
  field        dimension
0     a              NaN
1     b            [abc]
2     e       [efg, xyz]
3     r  [abc, def, xyz]
```

But if no problem if `NaN` in lists:

```
df =(df.groupby(df['field'].ffill())['dimension']
       .apply(list)
       .reset_index())
print (df)
  field        dimension
0     a            [nan]
1     b            [abc]
2     e       [efg, xyz]
3     r  [abc, def, xyz]
```